# What would be regular expression of finding all strings starts with $ in java

Tags: java, regex

I am having one string containing "This is a time to get involve into $FO, $RTP, $DFG and $RG"

Comment: Where is the question? Or at least a question mark?

Comment: He just wants somebody to give him his answer. No learning required that way.

Comment: @RohitJain, I guess in the title. Answer would be `\$\w+`.

Comment: rubbish. what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work too

```
String str="This is a time to get involve into $FO, $RTP, $DFG and $RG" ;
    String[] arr=str.split(" ");
    for (String i:arr){
         if(i.indexOf("$")==0){
             System.out.println(i.replaceAll("\\,",""));
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use following regular expression:

```
"\\$\\w+"
```

- `$` should be escaped.
- `\w` match digits, alphabet, `_`.

  - If you need only match alphabets, use `[a-zA-Z]` instead.